# Can't configure a block in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, configure, block

I am using Drupal 7.9 and CKEditor 7.x-1.6. I don't know what is the reason why I can't configure or edit the contents of my custom-made blocks. If I want do edit the contents (refering to pages and other content-types) of the drupal, I am able to change its contents.

[image]

I created some blocks and put in some contents and images. I called in some templates to show the contents, and the contents we're shown successfully. But if i want to edit it's content/s, after I clicked on the configure link, I couldn't see the contents..only a blank.. 
[image]

Do I have to change some settings of the CKEditor? or in the drupal 7 itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the text format to Plain HTML for debug reason and check if the content shows ok. Maybe that is the WYSIWYG issue.

Comment: I've got the same setup and issue. When I return to a block with CKEditor enabled it's blank. If I disable the module it's OK.